# which barcode sdk for iOS and Android I should use to scan IMEI number on mobile wrapper

Tags: android, ios, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to scan the barcode of IMEI of mobile device using mobile application. Current barcode type of IMEI is of 15 numeric digit, as shown in following image :

[image]

1. Please let me know the barcode codec type it is using?
2. SDK to scan this barcode for iOS application
3. SDK to scan this barcode for Android application

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of Barcode SDKs out there that can read the IMEI barcodes which is a Code128 type Barcode.

The company I work for has a [Barcode SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/barcode) that supports reading over 100 1D and 2D barcode types including Code128 on many different platforms including iOS and Android.

Here is all the code you would need in order to read these types of barcodes on your devices:

**Android**

```java
BarcodeData data = null; 
data = mBarcodeEngine.getReader().readBarcode(<image to be processed>, <screen coordinates to search in>, <barcode symbologies to search for>); return data;
```

**iOS Obj-c**

```cxx
data = [_barcodeEngine.reader readBarcodes:rasterImage 
searchBounds:LeadRectZero symbologies:enabledSymbologies options:_barcodeReadOptions error:&error];
```

**iOS Swift**

```swift
data = try? self.barcodeEngine.reader.readBarcode(rasterImage, searchBounds: 
LeadRectZero, symbologies: enabledSymbologies, options: self.barcodeReadOptions)
```